# Phusion-Passenger 4 creating more ( 200 + ) process than max pool size

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, phusion

we are running application on passenger 4 and the configuration settings are

PassengerMaxPoolSize 40

PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp 40

PassengerPoolIdleTime 150

PassengerMaxRequests 1500

PassengerBufferResponse on

PassengerSpawnMethod smart

PassengerMinInstances 25

PassengerMaxRequestQueueSize 0

When i check passenger-memory-stats i see more than 200+ passenger process and in passenger-status it shows well below the max pool size.

why is this process larger than max pool size. It should be below max pool size.My Db connections are increasing drastically max db connection (1500 in my case) is reached very often and i start to get too many connection error in application. 
Any help ??

Comment: Which exactly Passenger version are you using? Can you post the exact output of passenger-memory-stats?

Comment: passenger-memory-stats
Version: 4.0.40
Date   : 2015-09-04 13:39:16 +0530

---------- Apache processes ----------
PID    PPID   VMSize    Private  Name
--------------------------------------
1242   31248  143.1 MB  0.8 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd -f
### Processes: 51
### Total private dirty RSS: 32.56 MB

------ Passenger processes ------
PID    VMSize     Private   Name
---------------------------------
### Processes: 37
### Total private dirty RSS: 10247.67 MB

These 37 process has three watchdog/helper and logging agent rest are passenger process.

Comment: Where as my passenger status shows
passenger-status
Version : 4.0.40
Date    : 2015-09-04 13:39:37 +0530
Instance: 31248
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 40
Processes     : 25
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------

Comment: @hongli I often see that my passenger-status shows less than 40 instances but passenger process normally shoots up in passenger-memory-stats

Comment: Can you paste with gist.github.com? StackOverflow is not good for pasting output. In any case, I think you can solve this by just upgrading to the latest Passenger version. Newer Passenger versions are much better at enforcing resource limits.

Comment: Thanks @hongli will try the latest passenger version. Also I am suspecting my spawnling processes are increasing the process count. Will dive in to get more findings.